# permutate two streams without the need of materialization

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two streams which I must materialize into two lists to get the permutations from both streams:

```
public Stream<Permutation> getAll() {

   Stream.Builder<Permutation> all = Stream.builder();
   
   // unfortunately, I must collect it into a list
   var list1 = IntStream.iterate(0, d -> d - 1).limit(1000000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   var list2 = IntStream.iterate(0, d -> d + 1).limit(1000000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   
   // I must use a classic loop (and cannot operate on those streams) to  avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException
   for(var l1: list1) {
       for(var l2: list2) {
           // the permutation class consists of two int properties
           all.add(new Permutation(l1, l2));
       }
   }
   return all.build();
}
```

Is there a way **to avoid** to materialize `list1` and `list2` and operate only on those streams to return the permutations? I have tried it but I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

Therefore I have materialized the two lists and used a classic loop. However, I would like to improve the performance by doing the following steps:

- avoid the materialization of `list1` and `list2`
- and maybe also use parallelStream for `list1` and `list2` to get the permutations faster

Is this possible? If so, how?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Andreas for the solution which works so far. However, I wonder how I can create a permutation from two getAll()-streams without the need to materialize it in between:

```
// The `Permutations` class holds two `Permuation`-instances.
Stream<Permutations> allPermutations(){

    Stream<Permutation> stream1 = getAll();
    Stream<Permutation> stream2 = getAll();
 
    // returns java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    return stream1.flatMap(s1->stream2.map(s2->new Permutations(s1,s2));

}
```

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. There is only a `Permutation`-Class.

Comment: The `Permutations` class holds two `Permuation`-instances.

Comment: Since streams are read-once, you cannot generate a cross join without materializing one of the them, given that one of the streams must be iterated multiple times.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear, I need to materialize only one stream and then it works. Thanks.

Comment: In your case, with the sample code in the question, there is no need to materialize, since re-generating the stream is very fast. Sure, materializing might be slightly faster, but it also consumes memory, so it's a compromise between time and space whether you want to materialize one of the streams. Materializing might cause out-of-memory, so I'd recommend re-streaming over materializing, unless the streaming is slow (not the case here).

Comment: How can I re-generate the stream? I already called getAll() two times so I have two distinct streams..don't know how to re-generate while looping both streams..

Comment: `iterate()` generates a new stream. The answer below re-generates the second `IntStream` for each value of the first `IntStream`. Why are you suddenly trying to cross join two streams that are already cross joins themselves? The `IntStream` generates 1,000,000 values (integers), so the cross join stream returned by `getAll()` will have 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 = 1,000,000,000,000 values (`Permuation` objects). If you cross join those, you end up with 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 values. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Oh I understand, you mean: create the second stream for each iteration of the first stream..hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```java
public Stream<Permutation> getAll() {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, d -> d - 1).limit(1000000).boxed()
            .flatMap(l1 -> IntStream.iterate(0, d -> d + 1).limit(1000000)
                                    .mapToObj(l2 -> new Permutation(l1, l2)));
}
```

The caller can decide whether or not to use parallel processing:

```java
// Sequential
Stream<Permutation> stream = getAll();

// Parallel
Stream<Permutation> stream = getAll().parallel();
```

No need to call `sequential()`, since `iterate()` returns a new sequential `IntStream`.

Comment: Andreas: the `mapToObj` (last line) does not exist, You mean `map(..)`, or?

Comment: @nimo23 See javadoc for [`IntStream.mapToObj(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-). It surely exists. It seems you missed the fact that I removed the `boxed()` call from the second `IntStream`. There is no need to box `l2`, since you added comment saying that `Permutation` constructor arguments are `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks! All works and there is only one question, I **extend the above question** to make it more clear what I wanted to achieve. I already accept your answer, so far. Thanks again!

Comment: After comparing, I come to the conclusion that I will stick to the classic for-loop by materializing each IntStream and then iterating. With the classic for-loop I get an avergage time of 708ms (for 20.000 objects) whereas with the stream with flatMap and mapToObj, I get an avg time of 1100ms. Cannot see any benefit in using the flatMap solution. I also tried it with paralellStream. It would even be slightly slower. However, thanks. I learned..;)